# Why does it show a white window in Haskell / Fungen?

Tags: haskell

I'm using Fungen to create a game in Haskell, and I run it without problems in my pc with Windows XP. The problem is when I try to make it run in another PC. I've tried running it in other 3 PCs with Windows XP, but when the game window opens, it is all white and I cann't do anything in the game. The strange thing is, that I can run the classical Fungen examples (Pong and Worms) in the other PCs without problems. I have a friend that can run my example in Windows 7 with a PC similar to mine.

The other PCs have worse hardware than mine, so I think that that's the problem here, but I want to know if it's something else.

Comment: Had this a number of times when the versions of the installed Haskell(platform) were different on both systems.

Comment: I installed the same Haskell platform in all the PCs :(